# File is not saved in UTF-8 encoding even when I set encoding to UTF-8

Tags: java, encoding

When I check my file with Notepad++ it's in ANSI encoding. What I am doing wrong here?

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF8");
try
        {           
            out.write(text);
            out.flush();
        } finally
        {
            out.close();
        }
```

UPDATE:

This is solved now, reason for jboss not understanding my xml wasn't encoding, but it was naming of my xml. Thanx all for help, even there really wasn't any problem...

Comment: Does your text have any non-ASCII characters? Notepad just does a heuristic check on the data).

Comment: in application its xml and my testing file its only alphabets

Comment: Your comment below indicates that this is not the actual code that's causing a problem. Please edit with the actual code, the message that JBoss is giving you, and a sample of the XML file.

Comment: And how are you creating this XML file? If you're writing strings to a Writer, I can pretty much guarantee that you're writing it wrong. Build a DOM and use a serializer.

Comment: Its just simple jndi datasource xml file

Comment: @newbie: It's “letter”, or “alphabetical character”.  The word “alphabet” means the whole set of these letters, not a single element.  As I've written below in my comment to Justice, this mistake helps me understand something about your question, but it would really be better if you stated it more precisely, in particular by showing us the exact piece of code that exhibits the issue, not some knockoff which you *think* is the core of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 is designed to be, in the common case, rather indistinguishable from ANSI. So when you write text to a file and encode the text with UTF-8, in the common case, it looks like ANSI to anyone else who opens the file.

- UTF-8 is 1-byte-per-character for all ASCII characters, just like ANSI.
- UTF-8 has all the same bytes for the ASCII characters as ANSI does.
- UTF-8 does not have any special header characters, just as ANSI does not.

It's only when you start to get into the non-ASCII codepoints that things start looking different.

But in the common case, byte-for-byte, ANSI and UTF-8 are identical.

Comment: That is not true that ANSI and UTF-8 are usually identical. ANSI and UTF-8 are only identical when only-ASCII characters are used (codes between 0-127). Non ASCII characters such as "áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ" have multibyte encoding (2 bytes for these specific set) in UTF-8. In ANSI every character is encoded with 1 byte . When are ANSI and UTF-8 identical? When "strange" characters are not used, understanding by "strange" any character (letter/punctuation/accent) not found in English language.

Comment: That's precisely the point: “newbie” has, no doubt, a lot of non-ASCII characters in his input, as hints his mistaken use of “alphabet” as “element of an alphabet”, which is common among English speakers in India, in particular.  He uses “ANSI” to mean that his file is interpreted as using some 8-bit encoding (probably Windows-1252) and comes out as meaningless sequence of accented characters (“its only alphabets”).

Comment: The "common case" is bytes 00 to 7F. When all codepoints in the text can be represented in UTF-8 in a single byte in the 00-7F range, then that UTF-8-encoded text is ANSI. That includes most English-language-with-no-accents text.

Comment: You folks keep using "ANSI" in a very strange way.  I have no earthly idea what it means!

Comment: @tchrist: Lots of people seem to use "ANSI" as a shorthand for "windows-1252". I suspect this is because a lot of older MSDN pages do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating an XML file (as your comments imply), I would *strongly* recommend that you use the XML libraries to output this *and* write the correct XML encoding header. Otherwise your character encoding won't conform to XML standards and other tools (like your JBoss instance) will rightfully complain.

```
    // Prepare the DOM document for writing
    Source source = new DOMSource(doc);

    // Prepare the output file
    File file = new File(filename);
    Result result = new StreamResult(file);

    // Write the DOM document to the file
    Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    xformer.transform(source, result);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as plain text. The problem is that an application is decoding character data without you telling it which encoding the data uses.

Although many Microsoft apps rely on the presence of a Byte Order Mark to indicate a Unicode file, this is by no means standard. [The Unicode BOM FAQ says more.](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom10)

You can add a BOM to your output by writing the character `'\uFEFF'` at the start of the stream. [More info here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_boms). This should be enough for applications that rely on BOMs.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no BOM (and Java doesn't output one for UTF8, it doesn't even recognize it), the text is identical in ANSI and UTF8 encoding as long as only characters in the ASCII range are being used. Therefore Notepad++ cannot detect any difference.

(And there seems to be an [issue with UTF8 in Java](http://tripoverit.blogspot.com/2007/04/javas-utf-8-and-unicode-writing-is.html) anyways...)

Comment: This isn't really an issue. There are many cases where you don't want your UTF-8 data prefixed by a BOM. Unicode BOM FAQ: http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom10

Comment: It is one of the possibilities to automatically (and pretty reliably) detect the difference between UTF-8 and ASCII or ANSI character sets. How are you otherwise going to know UTF-8 from something else?

Comment: I'm not disputing that you can (or whether you should) use a BOM in any individual case; you are right that it is certainly a possibility. However, there are too many cases where a BOM will break the data (e.g. unix scripts; appending to a file) or will be completely unnecessary (e.g. database records) for Java to prefix every UTF-8 encoded stream with U+FEFF. I would just not describe this as an issue with Java so much as an issue with developers being ignorant of how to work with encodings and how/when to use BOMs.

Comment: @McDowell: I completely agree. Note that I was just explaining why UTF-8 could not be detected by Notepad++ for ASCII text, and that Java has issues with UTF-8 BOMs. Just trying to put the facts on the table so that the problem can be understood; which way to go always depends on the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

The IANA registered type is "UTF-8", not "UTF8". However, Java should throw an exception for invalid encodings, so that's probably not the problem.

I suspect that Notepad is the problem. Examine the text using a hexdump program, and you should see it properly encoded.

Comment: I create XML file that should be encoded in UTF-8, but jboss cannot udnestand that file, but when I change encoding manually with Notepad++ to UTF-8, then jboss understands XML which is supposed to be in UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to write a BOM at the beginning of the file? BOM is the only thing that can tell the editor the file is in UTF-8. Otherwise, the UTF-8 file can just look like Latin-1 or extended ANSI.

You can do it like this,

```
public final static byte[] UTF8_BOM = {(byte)0xEF, (byte)0xBB, (byte)0xBF};
...
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
os.write(UTF8_BOM);
os.flush();
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF8");
try
    {                       
            out.write(text);
            out.flush();
    } finally
    {
            out.close();
    }
```